# Regex to stringify guid

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a regex newbie and I want to convert the following method to regex to follow best practices:

```
public static string StringifyGUID(string strGUID)
    {
        ///TODO: Regex function
        string stringifiedGUID = Regex.Replace(strGUID, "[{}]", "");
        string stringifiedGUID2 = stringifiedGUID.Replace("-", "");
        string stringifiedGUID3 = stringifiedGUID2.ToLower();
        return stringifiedGUID3;
    }
```

Also please tell me if there are any good regex tools I can use to help me learn. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a Regex problem.  Why are you creating 3 strings?  If you gave sample input and output it would be easier to understand you.

Comment: Yeah this would be more painful in regex than it is now. This so calls for a pass through tr but that's not so commonly available as a library function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression here - you can use `Guid.Parse` and `Guid.ToString` to solve this easily:

```
public static string StringifyGuid(string s)
{
    var guid = Guid.Parse(s);
    return guid.ToString("N");
}
```

`ToString("N")` specifies that you want only digits without separators, [as explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx).

To answer your second question, http://www.regular-expressions.info has many in-depth information and tutorials that help you learning, while https://regex101.com will help you understand, test and build Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to do it is to combine `Substrin` method and `StringBuilder` class:

```
// Example of GUID to checking:
// {6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF}

var result = new StringBuilder();
result.Append(source.Substring(1, 8));
result.Append(source.Substring(10, 4));
result.Append(source.Substring(15, 4));
result.Append(source.Substring(20, 4));
result.Append(source.Substring(25, 12));
return result.ToString();
```

And you don't need regex to this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Dot-Net expert, but you should be able to do the replacement with one regex.

```
Regex.Replace(strGUID, "[{}-]+", "");
```